# XSLT FO Horizontal alignment of inline container

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, antenna-house

I'm trying to align an inline container horizontally, but I can't find the corresponding FO attribute like display-align for vertical alignment.

Here is some example code without any alignment:

```
<fo:inline-container background-color="white" border-style="solid" border-width="2mm" border-color="white">
    <fo:block font-family="Blablabla" text-align="center" font-size="54pt" space-after="6mm" text-indent="0mm" last-line-end-indent="0mm" alignment-baseline="central">
        ...
    </fo:block>
</fo:inline-container>
```

The whole thing is going to be processed with AntennaHouse 5.2.

Thanks in advance
Stavros

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `text-align="center"` to the `fo:block` (or similar) that contains the `fo:inline-container`:

```
 <fo:block text-align="center">
    <fo:inline-container background-color="white" border-style="solid" border-width="2mm" border-color="white">
      <fo:block font-family="Blablabla" text-align="center" font-size="54pt" space-after="6mm" text-indent="0mm" last-line-end-indent="0mm">
          ...
       </fo:block>
    </fo:inline-container>
 </fo:block>
```

Also, your `alignment-baseline="central"` doesn't do anything since `alignment-baseline` doesn't apply to `fo:block` and is not inherited.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#alignment-baseline